# How to join a layer once when toggling visibility?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-joins

I have a set of layers contained in several groups (*"First group"*, *"Second group"* and *"Third group"*). I created a function where when a layer from any of these groups has its visibility toggled, it is joined by a 'parent' layer which shares the same name as the group the layer is in:

[image: Example]

So in the example shown, if I click on `Layer_1`, it will be joined to the `First Group` layer. If I click on `Layer_8`, it will be joined to the `Third group` layer etc.

---

The problem is that when I click on a layer from the "First, Second or Third group", it is joined several times instead of just the once.

For example, if I click `Layer_3` once and then check the Joins properties:

[image: Problem]

---

Here is the code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
main_group = root.findGroup('Main group')
layerField = 'ID'

def update_joins():
    for group in main_group.children():
        layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName( group.name() )[-1]
        for child in group.children():
            node = root.findLayer(child.layer().id()) 
            if node.isVisible() == Qt.Checked:  
                childField = 'ID'
                joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
                joinObject.joinLayerId = child.layer().id()
                joinObject.joinFieldName = childField
                joinObject.targetFieldName = layerField
                joinObject.memoryCache = True
                layer.addJoin(joinObject) 
            else:
                layer.removeJoin(child.layer().id())

root.visibilityChanged.connect(update_joins)
```

---

I'm not exactly sure why it is being joined several times, is there a way to make sure it is only joined once?

I checked [QgsVectorJoinInfo](https://qgis.org/api/structQgsVectorJoinInfo.html) and the [QgsVectorLayer::vectorJoins](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a6f1fe6b1cb4ff2c3dd12d310da94aa33) to see if it is possible to do a check (i.e. if this layer has been joined then `pass`) but couldn't find much information.

Comment: If you have layer3 on with one join and then you turn on layer4 does one join get added to layer3 and one added layer4 or does it automatically add many joins to both?

Comment: @artwork21 - Yes you are correct, one does get added to layer_3 and layer_4.

Comment: I think your logic right now is just looking what is on and not looking if the layer already has a join.  Outside of the function maybe define a dictionary with the keys being the layer names and the value being the join state (True or False).  Within the if statement before performing the join look into the dictionary and see if the join state value is True or False, if False perform the join and set the value in the dict to True.  Same for the else statement, if the layer is off remove the join (as you have) and set the related dictionary layer value to False.

Comment: @artwork21 - Good logic, thanks for mentioning it. I found that if I add `layer.removeJoin(child.layer().id())` directly after the `if node.isVisible() == Qt.Checked: ` statement, the final product is that the layer is only joined once. However, the unnecessary looping is not really efficient so will try and see about creating your logic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Thinking more about this using a dictionary to hold the layer names and the related layer join field name and evaluating each checked layer to see if it has the reference joined field should be a better method.  If join field is present, than skip, otherwise perform the join.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
main_group = root.findGroup('Main group')
layerField = 'ID'
layerFieldRef = {'First group':'FirstGroupLayerFieldName', 
               'Second group':'SecondGroupLayerFieldName', 
               'Second group':'SecondGroupLayerFieldName',                    
               'Second group':'SecondGroupLayerFieldName',   
               'Second group':'SecondGroupLayerFieldName', 
               'Third group':'ThirdGroupLayerFieldName', 
               'Third group':'ThirdGroupLayerFieldName',           
               'Third group':'ThirdGroupLayerFieldName'
                }

def update_joins():
    for group in main_group.children():
        layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName( group.name() )[-1]
        for child in group.children():
            node = root.findLayer(child.layer().id()) 
            if node.isVisible() == Qt.Checked:
                # check if related layer join field is present, if not present than join
                fields = layer.pendingFields()
                for key in layerFieldRef:
                    if fields.indexFromName(key + '_' + layerFieldRef[key]) == -1:  
                        childField = 'ID'
                        joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
                        joinObject.joinLayerId = child.layer().id()
                        joinObject.joinFieldName = childField
                        joinObject.targetFieldName = layerField
                        joinObject.memoryCache = True
                        layer.addJoin(joinObject) 
            else:
                layer.removeJoin(child.layer().id())

root.visibilityChanged.connect(update_joins)
```

This should eliminate extra joins on a layer that already has a join.

Comment: Thanks for the update, seems to work fine so happy to accept this ;)